# Views Sub tab on user account page

Tags: 7, views, routes

I am trying to create a menu structure on the user profile page like:

```
/user/%/content = Main tab (next to View, Edit) on /user/%uid
/user/%/content/published = Sub tab showing published nodes
/user/%/content/unpublished = Sub tab showing unpublished nodes
```

I have tried using /user/%/content/all as the main default tab.
Tried setting sub tab as default tab and not default.

Ive gotten:

```
    View, Edit, Published, Unpublished, My Content

    View, Edit, Published
                 -Published
                 -My Content

View, Edit, My Content (with no child tabs)
```

I can't seem to find the correct settings to get My Content to be the main tab, with Published and Unpublished to be sub tabs to My Content.

I tried swapping the settings for Published and My Content but that didn't work.

Does My Content need to be the default tab? Or does Publish need to be the default tab with My Content as the "parent already exists"?

Any help getting the tab structure sorted out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Under *Page settings*, in the view settings, you will find the *Menu* option; you need to set it to:

- *Menu tab* for user/%/content
- *Default menu tab* for user/%/content/published
- *Menu tab* for user/%/content/unpublished

> [image: screenshot]

This is how it appears.

> [image: screenshot]

#### PS

I used the Tracker view that comes with the Views module, and altered it to obtain the desired result.